# How to make the container take the full width on the right when it is in a wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I try to make my green container take all the width on the right when it is in a wrapper.I don't know if anyone has another solution that could help me.

I specify that I have to put a background-image in the green block and therefore an after will not work

Here is what i have now
[image]

```css
 .o-wrapper {
    padding-right: 1.875rem;
    padding-left: 1.875rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 75rem;
 }

.page{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  &__scroll{
    width: rem(160px);
    max-width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 216px);
    background-color: $cRed;
    margin-right: rem(30px);
  }
  &__header-bg{
    background-color: $cGreen;
    position: absolute;
    left: 210px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  &__content{
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="page o-wrapper">
    <div class="page__header-bg"></div>
      <div class="page__scroll"></div>
      <div class="page__content">
        <HeaderHome />
        <div>{{ page.title }}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the result I would like to get
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to provide a screenshot or a working sample for your problem?

Comment: Please update the screenshot of the result. I think you posted the same screenshot.

Comment: No, it's not the same screenshot, the first one is the result I'm getting right now, so the green block doesn't take up the full width on the right and the second screenshot is this that I would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background:yellow;
}

.left{
width: 150px;
background: red;
}

.right{
  flex: 1;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
<div class = "left">
Left
</div>

<div class = "right">
Right
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I have a container all around with a size of 1200px

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).